# Does windows phone8.1 sdk support winjs/javascript as native

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I used C# develop a WP8 app. I'm wondering if the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK supports WinJS? 
I saw there are some news that windows phone 8.1 start to support WinJS

If so, I will move to WinJS for WP and WinRT both.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of February 2014, there is no official documentation available currently on Windows Phone 8.1.

So, any comments here would be speculative or based on confidential/leaked documentation. I would suspect that your question will be answered at the Microsoft BUILD 2014 conference in April 2014 (either confirmation or that it was just a rumor).

Given the information disclosed, you might also consider that WinRT applications would be possible on the Windows Phone 8.1+, which would mean that you could write a Win 8.1 Store application using C# and XAML that would run on both platforms. So, switching to WinJS might not be necessary if you wanted to continue to use your core XAML and C# skills.

Answer (score 1):

As of April 18th, 2014, yes, JavaScript and the WinJS framework are supported by Windows Phone 8.1.

Announcement here: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/04/18/winjs-on-windows-phone-8-1/